# Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent)

Tags: java, actionlistener, connectivity

i am trying to connect oracle sql with java and want to perform few queries but i am getting error that

```
error: Conn is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
class Conn extends JFrame implements ActionListener
```

here is my code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;

class Conn extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("login page");
        JLabel fname,lname,pn;
        JTextField fname1,lname1,pn1;
        JButton sbmt,updt,dlt,slct;

        static Connection conn;

    Conn()
    {
        fname = new JLabel("First name");
        fname.setBounds(5,50,100,20);

        fname1 = new JTextField(10);
        fname1.setBounds(100,50,100,20);

        lname = new JLabel("Last Name");
        lname.setBounds(5, 100, 100,20);

        lname1 = new JTextField(10);
        lname.setBounds(100,100,100,20);

        pn = new JLabel("Phone No.");
       pn.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 50);

        pn1 =  new JTextField(10);
        pn1.setBounds(50,50,50,50);

        sbmt = new JButton("Insert");
        sbmt.setBounds(50,50,50,50);


        add(fname);
        add(fname1);

        add(lname);
        add(lname1);

        add(pn);
        add(pn1);

        add(sbmt);

        sbmt.addActionListener(this);

    }

  public void actionListener(ActionEvent e)
  {
      if (e.getSource()==sbmt)
      {
          System.out.println("sbmt button clicked");
      }
  }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","username","password");
             conn.close();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);

                }


        Conn con = new Conn();

        con.setSize(400,400);
        con.setLayout(null);
        con.setVisible(true);
    }    
}
```

output :

```
/home/jayu/NetBeansProjects/projects/conn/src/conn/Conn.java:5: error: Conn is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
class Conn extends JFrame implements ActionListener
```

Compiler : NetBeans

How can i solve this error, i don't want to remove `implements ActionListener`
.please anybody correct this error without removing `implements ActionListener.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the error message says it all.
In your case, you added the method:

```
public void actionListener(ActionEvent e)
```

but this should actually be:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
```

since this is the actual method in the interface you are implementing.

Comment: Furthermore, always add the `@Override` annotation. Besides making the code more readable, it also gives you an error in case the name of the method is not correct.

Comment: yeah i did mistake in writing method.Thank you.

Comment: @helloword if your question is answered, could you mark one of the answers as accepted? that way other people will know it is answered

Answer (score 2):

Because your class implements interface

```
public interface ActionListener extends EventListener {
    void actionPerformed(ActionEvent var1);
}
```

You need to have it's method implemented:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {...}
```

I assume that this method has wrong name:

```
public void actionListener(ActionEvent e){...}
```

So rename it to `actionPerformed` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You must implement the method if you want to keep the interface ActionListener.
Just switch the name of actionListener() to actionPerformed(). Otherwise you can also keep actionListener() and implement actionPerformed() so that he do nothing

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove ActionListener implementation from your class:

```
class Conn extends JFrame
```

Remove your actionListener method and add this instead of sbmt.addActionListener(this);

```
 sbmt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             if (e.getSource()==sbmt)
              {
                  System.out.println("sbmt button clicked");
              }

        }
    });
```

***EDIT:***

I missed you don't want to remove ActionListener implementation, so as somebody else already said you have to change your method:

```
public void actionListener(ActionEvent e)
```

{

into:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
}
```

Comment: the OP asked for a solution "without removing implements ActionListener".

Comment: I completely missed this from my smartphone. Since the answer was already given, I'll leave this here for somebody else

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        
}
```

Try to put this in your public class and outside of any constructor. Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Thanks for your answer.  In this case it looks like your answer is similar to other answers to this question, so consider upvoting one of those instead of repeating.  Have fun!